# When Would Ruby fail to Execute "sleep(0.1)"?

Tags: ruby

When would Ruby ever throw a `#<NoMethodError: undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass>` when executing the code `sleep(0.1)`?

I've noticed this happening, but I can't figure out what is undefined.

Comment: This works for me in `irb`. You'll need to narrow the problem down a little.

Comment: Show us the code in context that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: This turned out to be from an uncaught exception in another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code will never produce that error. You are looking in the wrong spot.